# How to set a timercalling a member method in F#?

Tags: f#

I am trying to achieve this:

```
type Test() =

    member val MyTimer : Timer = new Timer(TimerCallback TimerEvent)

    member mutable Status : bool = false
    ...

    member this.StartTimer =
        this.MyTimer....

    member this.TimerEvent =
        if this.Status...
```

I need to create a timer that is part of the class instance, needs to be referenced by several methods (to start / stop it) but also, the timer ballback needs to be able to access some of the inner states.

I can't find the syntax to create the timer object so that it has access to class members and class members have access to it.

But I think I'm having some confusion:

It looks like I can do the timer like this:

```
        member this.Timer : Timer = new Timer(TimerCallback (fun x -> printfn "%A" x))
```

but I though member was reserved for methods and val for the fields? can anyone clarify this? I can do member this.xxx, but I can't do val this.xxx..

Comment: It looks like you are using System.Threading.Timer here. Is that the kind of timer you really want to use, or will you use the more commonly used System.Timer.Timer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post because I need to implement a scheduled job in F# for the first time.
I'm also learning F# and it is the first time I saw "val", so I read something about it.

Regarding your question.
"member val ... " is a particular case described here:
[The val Kweyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/explicit-fields-the-val-keyword)

> Another use of the **val** keyword is in conjunction with the **member** keyword to declare an auto-implemented property.

I think this answer your question.

Said that, I looked up to your code:

```
member this.Timer : Timer = new Timer(TimerCallback (fun x -> printfn "%A" x))
```

This is not correct to me because it exposes the Timer publicly.
I like the idea to have an object (the Timer) declared but not initialized, so that I can refer to its instance within multiple methods (Start/Stop) and (most important) Dispose it properly.

So, also regarding your doubt about the syntax...

> I can't find the syntax to create the timer object so that it has access to class members and class members have access to it.

I came out with the following example:

```ml
open System
open System.Threading

type public ExampleJob () as me =

    let timer_elapsed:TimerCallback = TimerCallback(fun (state) -> me.OnCall(state) )
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable private timer:Timer    // no need to initialize

    member __.IsActive with get() = __.timer <> null

    member __.Start(frequency:TimeSpan) = 
        __.Stop()  // Dispose previous timer if exists
        __.timer <- new Timer(timer_elapsed)        
        __.timer.Change(0, int(frequency.TotalMilliseconds)) |> ignore              

    member __.Stop() =
        if __.timer <> null then __.timer.Dispose() ; __.timer <- null 

    member private __.OnCall (state:obj) =
        // do the real work here
        // The state object is the Timer object. 
        Console.WriteLine(sprintf"OnCall(%i) at %s" ((state :?> Timer).GetHashCode()) (DateTime.Now.ToString("ss:fff")))


    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose(): unit = 
            this.Stop()
```

Checking the Timer itself is enough to expose the *Status* (IsActive/IsRunning).
*Start/Stop* can be called in any sequence an number of times. A new call to *Start()* will reset the current timer to the new desired frequency.
**It is not thread safe** and I haven't tested it enough, so I'm not 100% sure the timer "survives" when/if the whole class is no more referenced.
Anyway I hope this is a useful example.

**[Update]**

new version with the suggestion of Ben

```ml
open System

type ExampleJob () =

    let timer = new Timers.Timer()
    let OnCall = fun(args) -> 
                 // do real job here
                 Console.WriteLine(sprintf"OnCall(%O) at %s" args (DateTime.Now.ToString("ss:fff")))    

    do timer.Elapsed.Add(OnCall) // carefull to add it only once

    member this.IsActive with get() = timer.Enabled

    member this.Start(frequency:TimeSpan) =
        timer.Interval <- frequency.TotalMilliseconds        
        timer.AutoReset <- true
        timer.Enabled <- true   
        OnCall() // first call (if needed)
        timer.Start()  

    member this.Stop() = timer.Enabled <- false                        

    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose(): unit = 
            timer.Dispose()
```

Comment: I suggest you switch to System.Timers.Timer unless you have a specific need for System.Threading.Timer. Then you can control the timer without allocating and deallocating it on start and stop. Just use Enabled and the other properties.

Comment: Remove "public" and "as me". Use "let timer = Timer()". Don't use double underscore if the compiler lets you use single underscore. Don't use underscore as a variable, as in "if __.timer <>" - that's considered quite bad - but instead use "x", or "this" if you prefer. Callback can be "let callback (a: ElapsedEventArgs) =" and assign it with "timer.Elapsed.Add callback".